# How to avoid running some steps in Background part in a feature file for some scenario in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

According to the below feature, How to avoid running the second step in feature Back-ground only for the second Scenario.

Any ideas ?

Background:

```
Given Do given

And Do this(No need to run for the second scenario)

And Do this
```

Scenario:

User is - Test User One

And user name is

Scenario:

```
User is - Test User Two


And user name is
```

Comment: All the statements of the Background are supposed to get executed before the execution of each and every scenario. I don't think so what you are looking for is possible. You can remove the second step from the Background and add that individually to the scenarios where it should execute.

Answer (score 0):

Move it into a different feature file. If it needs a different background to other scenarios in the file then you need to put it in its own place where you can explain its different background.